# Error when creating a new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I try create a new maven project (with several archetypes, not only the one below), I am facing this error:

```
Unable to create project from archetype [org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:RELEASE]
Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'
```

Anyone know why this is happening, and how to solve it?

Comment: In the pom.xml file of your project, include this. <packaging>pom</packaging>

Comment: but i don't have a project yet (I am trying create one). what pom.xml i should modify?

Comment: what command did you use to create the project?

Comment: Be sure to spell all the options correctly.  A misspelling is what brought me here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems that your directory is not empty.
this command line works for me: (in an empty directory)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=fr.myGroupId -DartifactId=MyApplication -Dpackagename=fr.myGroupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

the result is:

```
[INFO] Using property: groupId = fr.myGroupId
[INFO] Using property: artifactId = MyApplication
Define value for property 'version':  1.0-SNAPSHOT: : 
[INFO] Using property: package = fr.myGroupId
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: fr.myGroupId
artifactId: MyApplication2
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: fr.myGroupId
 Y: : 
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Old (1.x) Archetype: maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: fr.myGroupId
[INFO] Parameter: packageName, Value: fr.myGroupId
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: fr.myGroupId
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: MyApplication2
[INFO] Parameter: basedir, Value: /home/ABC-OBJECTIF/philippe.demanget/workspace/pdemanget/tmp/mvn
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] project created from Old (1.x) Archetype in dir: /home/ABC-OBJECTIF/philippe.demanget/workspace/pdemanget/tmp/mvn/MyApplication2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.764s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 22 13:35:17 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/216M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I can reproduce your error by doing this command line inside the newly created directory:

```
cd MyApplication
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=fr.myGroupId -DartifactId=MyApplication -Dpackagename=fr.myGroupId -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
[...] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: It don't need to be empty, it just need there is no `pom.xml` in current dir, otherwise current dir will be thought as the parent project, and their packing type need to match

Comment: Bump into the same error with maven 3.6.0 and I am sure the directory is empty.

Comment: @KokHowTeh I also have the same issue as you and am on Maven 3.6.0. Trying to create new Maven package, keep giving me the error that "... it is not of packaging type 'pom'."

Answer (score 23):

I got the same issue, solved by manually removing a unused **pom.xml** file at the root of workspace directory

Comment: This is exact the issue I got, a `pom.xml` from where I execute the command cause the issue, and issue fixed after remove the file. Probably it's because `mvn` though the current dir is an parent project when there is a `pom.xml` file, and the packing type from the pom.xml is different from what is specified in the command.

Comment: Holy crap, I spent like three hours trying to figure out my issue. I just removed the ```pom.xml``` like you said and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

You have to remove the already existing pom.xml or if you need it to execute the maven command, try adding `<packaging>pom</packaging>` 
to your pom.

Since if you have an already existing in the current directory, it should match with the package structure. It is always to good to start with no pom file in the parent directory.

This should work.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem using Windows PowerShell in a newly created directory with nothing in it. I tried the command using the regular Windows Command Prompt, and it worked fine.

Comment: I actually didn't need a newly created directory.  Thanks, @Jonathan

Comment: It was the same for me, with Windows Powershell it returns errors, with regular command line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I simply created new workspace and it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the pom.xml in archtype project.
Worked for me like a champ