# Create maven project using Terminal

Tags: maven

Could you help me?
I try to create Maven project on Mac.
But I see this mistake in terminal:
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type ‘pom

I spent all day long for this issue tried to delete pom or used other methods. 
Could you help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when creating a new maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217454/error-when-creating-a-new-maven-project)

Comment: Can you specify the command that you used to create this project?